# Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jenkins, reactotron

When I run my Jenkins build for my React Native project it fails with the following errors:

```
Unable to resolve module `reactotron-core-client` from `/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/node_modules/reactotron-redux/dist/index.js`: Module does not exist in the module map

Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets'.
```

I followed the recommended `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` but I am not exactly sure that this would help, since it seems to me like it's a generic solution from the npm team.

React-Native version: 0.53.3 with `"reactotron-react-native": "3.5.0", "reactotron-redux": "3.1.0",`

How can I ensure this does not continue to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your `Jenkins` build server is unable to locate the `reactotron-core-client` module which is necessary to complete your `Jenkins` build. You can see this from your stack trace:

> Unable to resolve module `reactotron-core-client`

The recommended solution from the `npm` team of:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

is a generic solution because this command will remove your previous `node_modules` directory containing your project's dependencies and then reinstall the listed dependencies within in your project's `package.json` file. This may resolve issues stemming from your lock file as well as versioning issues if `npm` has been updated on your build server.

This solution may resolve your issue if all of your project's required libraries are listed within your `package.json` file. However, if the `reactotron-core-client` library isn't listed as a required dependency within your `package.json` file this problem will persist moving forward. Perhaps you could try the following:

`npm i --save reactotron-core-client`

as this will save and install the `reactotron-core-client` dependency for your project. By save I mean list this library as dependency within your `package.json` file.

Ideally, moving forward your best bet is to keep your *`package.json` file up-to-date with your project's dependencies as well as installing dependencies prior to attempting a `Jenkins` build.*

Hopefully that helps!